# Is it possible to manually scroll a JPG inside a div with 'little hand' cursor?

Tags: html

Is it possible to manually scroll a JPG inside a div with 'little hand' cursor by grabbing and draging the actual image?

Just when for example you have long horizontal bitmap and want to show it in small window so people scroll like in photo editors when you zoom in.

Answer (score 2):

You need some JavaScript magic to do this. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/bCuGM/.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #draggable {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 819px;
  }
</style>

<div id="container">
  <div id="draggable">
    <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2593/3884464511_a77144821e_b.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $("#draggable").draggable();
</script>
```

Comment: I am trying to get this working but it doesn't work. Should I just copy the function in the HEAD? Are there any crucial points apart from id matching the function id?

Comment: If you put the "$("#draggable").draggable();" stuff in the <head> of your document, you have to wrap it with a $(function() { /* CODE GOES HERE */ }); (DOM ready) since the elements are not present at this time. The "draggable" function is part of jQuery UI (=> http://jqueryui.com/), but you could also implement this behaviour without any third party libraries.

Comment: So what if I don't want to do it the way to put stuff inside <head>?

Comment: what is the proper normal way. I have my jquery library included (didn't know befor it's needed). I have my code and somewhere in the document I just put <script> $("#draggable").draggable();</script> ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using javascript and a bit of css.

On your image add a css rule with :

```
cursor: pointer;
```

using javascript, add mousedown, mousemove and mouseup events on your image. Then use javascript to change the scroll on the parent div